# Create a script that connects to network and if it fails fallbacks to ad-hoc network

Tags: networking, wifi

I'd like to create a script that tries to connect me to the WiFi specified by my wpa_supplicant conf, and if it fails, create an ad-hoc network. But I'm struggling with it.

Here is what I have done so far:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# create adhoc network function
createAdHocNetwork(){
    echo "Creating ad-hoc network"
    ifconfig wlan0 down
    iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
    iwconfig wlan0 essid AccessPoint
    ifconfig wlan0 11.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
    echo "Ad-hoc network created"
}

# connect to wifi function
connect(){
    echo "Trying to connect to configured wifi"
    ifdown wlan0
    wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /home/pi/pics/wpa_supplicant.conf
    ifup wlan0
    echo "Wifi configured"
}

echo "================================="
echo "Wifi setup"
echo "================================="
connect
echo "Checking connectivity..."
sleep 5s
ping -c 5 -I wlan0 google.com > /dev/null 2>&1
PINGSTATUS=$?
echo "Status"
echo $PINGSTATUS
if [ $PINGSTATUS -eq 0 ];
    then
        echo "Connected to WiFi"
    else
        echo "Wifi not connected, fallback to ad-hoc"
        createAdHocNetwork
fi

exit 0
```

It seems it connects to the configured Wi=Fi, but not for the ad-hoc.

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
# start interfaces upon start of the system
auto lo wlan0

# register loopback interface
iface lo inet loopback

# use dhcp and allow interface to be started when kernel detects a hotplug event
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# use manual ip configuration for wlan0 interface and allow hotplug as well
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

And my `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
ddns-update-style interim;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 11.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 11.0.0.2 11.0.0.150;
}
```

I can see the ad-hoc network from another computer, but I cannot connect to it, any ideas?

Comment: just curious, have you been able to make this work? It's such a cool idea and there's really no clear docs or examples on how to get it working right.

Comment: @Andres Well, no...

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue of your **WiFi Dongle**. If you are using **Edimax 7811UN** it will not work with Linux Kernels past `3.8+` versions for ad-hoc mode functions. This has been examined by me and [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157743/raspberry-pi-and-edimax-7811un-incompatibility-in-ad-hoc-mode/34458131#34458131) will assure you of it.

I suggest to use **Ralink Based RT5370 Chipset** dongles. They work well with ad-hoc mode as I use Ad-hoc mode everyday with almost 10 RPis.

Comment: I use rapsberry pi 3 with built in wifi

Comment: what is the on board WiFi adapter manufacture? can you do an `lsusb` and let me know?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with this adapter in ad-hoc mode since I can configure it OK while outside my script.

Comment: wait. you want to connect your Pi in ad hoc mode in order to use it as an Access-Point? You do know that ad-hoc mode has no access-point feature right?

Comment: I just want the Pi to connect the wifi configured in my wpa_supplicant conf. And if this wifi is not reachable, fallback to ad-hoc so I can connect to this wifi from another computer and go to a special page served on the Pi to configure another wifi.

Comment: Hi I was facing similar problems when you assign a Static IP for ad-hoc and using DHCP pool for another. It might be bit of an hack but do you think that using `sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel X` X being the channel number of your ad-hoc network will connect to your ad-hoc on Pi. At least that is how I connect to my ad-hoc network from my laptop. 

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 6 essid AccessPoint mode ad-hoc` and then I can ping the Pis. And also just so you know even though you can configure your Pi in ad-hoc doesn't really mean it will support ad-hoc you can see it but maybe adapter might not.